# Firebase v9 auth.currentUser is null after creating the user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's my JS code:

```
import { ref } from "vue"
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth'

const error = ref(null)
const isPending = ref(false)

const signup = async(email, password, displayName) => {
    error.value = null
    isPending.value = true

    try {
        const res = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(projectAuth, email, password)
        console.log(projectAuth.currentUser)

        if (!res) {
            console.log('Could not complete the signup')
            throw new Error('Could not complete the signup')
        }

        console.log(projectAuth.currentUser)
        await updateProfile(projectAuth.currentUser, {displayName})        
        error.value = null
        isPending.value = false

        return res
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message)
        error.value = err.message
        isPending.value = false
    }
}

const useSignup = () => {
    return {error, signup, isPending}
}

export default useSignup
```

My Vue3 application is calling the signup function in this script whenever a user is signing up. The createUserWithEmailAndPassword function is successful and the user shows up in firebase. But I want to also add a display name to my user, so I'm trying to use the updateProfile function to do that but there's a problem.

The problem is the projectAuth.currentUser is null even after creating the user and I can't figure out why??

Comment: Instances of `FirebaseError` have a `code` property that is often more useful than it's `message` property. In addition, `error.value` should be the error object itself rather than a message because authentication errors often have more data attached to them like credentials for merging duplicate accounts and the aforementioned `code` (useful for `switch`-based error handling. In addition, by naming convention, `error` implies an object describing an error and `errorMsg`/`errorMessage` is the string message of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a promise. Since your function is `async`, try adding `await`:

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(projectAuth, email, password)
console.log(projectAuth.currentUser)
```

Alternatively, you can pass `User` object to `updateProfile` directly from res:

```
const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(projectAuth, email, password)

await updateProfile(user, { displayName })
```